# How to put a delay on a loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

For example, if I want to make a timer, how do I make a delay in the loop so it counts in seconds and do not just loop through it in a millisecond?

Comment: You may `sleep 1` inside the loop to sleep for 1 second. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep

Comment: `[5,4,3,2,1].each {|n| puts n; sleep 1}` would count down from 5 to 1 each second, for example. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I agree with the previous comments--You can add an artificial delay with `sleep`. I would only add that you can sleep for fractions of seconds by providing fractional values like `Float`s and maybe `Rational`s as well.

Comment: Yeah that look awesome! But is it possible to make an input, (lets say 14) and it will count the exact same way but to the dedicated number?

Comment: I wrote this after looking at your code, but can not get it to work. 1.upto(x) { |number| puts number; sleep 1 } . Think it is something wrong with my input, using gets.chomp now.

Comment: @ZippO So you are literally asking how to just make a counter in Ruby?  Wrap Phrogz's top fragment below in a `def/end` to make a function `def counter(n)` and replace the `5` with `n`.

Comment: Nja. The reason I asked was becaus I wanted a countdown timer just like the first code you wrote, just trying to understand other ways of doing it. Ok thank you! Will try it!

Comment: Check https://github.com/celluloid/timers

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The 'comment' above is your answer, given the very simple direct question you have asked:

```
1.upto(5) do |n|
  puts n
  sleep 1 # second
end
```

It may be that you want to run a method periodically, without blocking the rest of your code. In this case, you want to use a Thread (and possibly create a mutex to ensure that two pieces of code are not attempting to modify the same data structure at the same time):

```
require 'thread'

items = []
one_at_a_time = Mutex.new

# Show the values every 5 seconds
Thread.new do
  loop do
    one_at_a_time.synchronize do
      puts "Items are now: #{items.inspect}"
      sleep 5
    end
  end
end

1000.times do
  one_at_a_time.synchronize do
    new_items = fetch_items_from_web
    a.concat( new_items )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

Somehow, many people think that putting a `sleep` method with a constant time interval as its argument will work. However, note that no method takes zero time. If you put `sleep(1)` within a loop, the cycle will surely be more than `1` second as long as you have some other content in the loop. What is worse, it does not always take the same time processing each iteration of a loop. Each cycle will take more than `1` second, with the error being random. As the loop keeps running, this error will contaminate and grow always toward positive. Especially if you want a timer, where the cycle is important, you do not want to do that.

The correct way to loop with constant specified time interval is to do it like this:

```
loop do
  t = Time.now
    #... content of the loop
  sleep(t + 1 - Time.now)
end
```

Comment: That produces the error: TypeError: can't convert Time into time interval

Comment: If the content of the loop takes more than one second or whatever the duration here, you will get this error, `ArgumentError: time interval must not be negative`